# Subtract amount in while loop in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I need a help with regards subtracting the total amount paid to monthly amortization,

for example, the user paid 13000 and his monthly amortization is 5000 only, I want to do looping like the following

- 5000
- 5000
- 3000

UPDATE

$total_payment = 13000;
$mi = 5000;

```
for ($x = 0; $mi <= $total_payment; $x++) {                 
    echo $total = $total_payment - $sales_mi, "<br/>";              
}
```

Comment: @Amarnasan thanks, I edit my post and insert what I did so far

Comment: Firstly in your echo, after `$sales_mi` you have a comma `,` instead of a dot `.` secondly you have to edit a little bit more, what result did you get whit this?

Comment: @CliffBurton With that he got two answers as result :)

Comment: @Amarnasan CliffBurton, don't comment if don't have anything to say. friendly reminder. :)

Comment: Dear PHP4lite, my comment came from another page while I was reviewing your question. When I posted my comment, in that page there weren't answers...what me and @Amarnasan did was just a contribution. If you don't want noisy comments in your post, just ignore them. If you can't live with this comments, please raise a flag (as soon as you can) and moderators/other reviewer will do the right thing. Friendly reminder ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$amort = 5000;
$remaining=15000;

for($remaining += $amort; $remaining > $amort; print((($remaining-=$amort) < $amort ? $remaining : $amort) . "<br>"));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is much better to add some explanations of what this code is doing as this is helping much more in solving the issue than just the code.

Comment: @Reeno You're right, but the accepted answer has  the same amount of explanation as mine but you didn't complain about it. Why is that?

Comment: Your answer showed up in the review queue [http://stackoverflow.com/review] so I commented it. The other answer didn't show up there

Comment: Oh, i guess it went automatically there because I didn't include a "Here is your code" preface? Such a pity... I will add that empty phrase in future answers, thank you!

Comment: @Amarnasan lastly, how do I insert query inside the for loop? I want to insert the value when looping. thank you

Comment: Easy: Just replace the last semicolon with a pair of curly brackets and put inside whatever you want, just like any other "for" structure.

Answer (score 3):

May be this could help -

```
$total_payment = 13000;
$sales_mi = 5000;
$count = ceil($total_payment / $sales_mi);


$new = [];
for ($x = 1; $x <= $count; $x++) {
   $total_payment -= $sales_mi;      
   if($total_payment >= 0) {
      $new[] = $sales_mi;
   } else {
      $new[] = $total_payment + $sales_mi;
      break;
   }
}

var_dump($new);
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(5000)
  [1]=>
  int(5000)
  [2]=>
  int(3000)
}
```

You can use the array as you want.